# Search for value in a panel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm using the pandas library, and have an instance of the [panel object](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.html). I want to find the number of elements that are equal to 0. I tried using the `count` command thusly:

```
panel.count(0)
```

However this returns the number of df within the axis 0, and I want to find the **number of elements within each df** of the panel that are equal to zero. Is there any built-in command to do that? Can anyone help me?

Comment: What kind of panel? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi amgaera, I don't really get what you mean with what kind of panel...? I tried different commands, e.g. value_counts(panel).

Comment: what is `panel`? that isn't a common technical jargon, that's a meaningless word. We have no context for you question. Please post the relevant code and what you tried to do (show it to us don't tell us about it theoretically)

Comment: Ok, I see. It is a pandas panel. Does this help? I could show all approches I have already tried. However, since I think there should be a very simple solution (command) I think it would only lead to confusions when showing all approches.

Comment: yes that helps **A LOT**. How else would we know you were talking about the `pandas` library?? Using our mind reading abilities? Now please post **your code**, *one thing* that you tried\expected to work (no need to list out a million explanations) and **what is your desired output**.

Comment: Also, have you [tried this?](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.count.html)

Comment: Ok, sorry I am not very experienced with python. One try: panel.count(). However, this seems to count the number of the axis 0 instead of the elements with value 0 in the panel. My desired output: How many elements are there in the panel that have value 0.

Comment: Sorry, have seen your answer too late. This is exactly what I tried. However, as described above, this returns the number of "df" per axis. I am interested in the values within all df of the panel. Hope I do not mess up the different names and you can understand what I mean..?

Comment: Edit your code in to the answer, and the desired output (not the desired action, what the actual solution is supposed to be). I understand the problem now, but someone with more knowledge in pandas might come along, and you want him to get it too without reading all the comments. Just edit in "I'm using the pandas library, this is my code..." `*<code>*` "I'm trying to get the values from the Panel object, and expect to get:" `*<code>*`. "I tried using count, but it does this and that. Can anyone help me?"

Comment: Looks a lot better (I edited it too). Hopefully some pandas expert will come along (I'm more of a web-development guy, but I'll take a peak at it later today if no one comes along). Bear in mind that there might not be a built in way to do what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.sum()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.sum.html) (and the axis argument controls which DataFrame slices you're summing over):

```
In [11]: p = pd.Panel([[[1, 1]], [[1, 2]], [[1, 2]]])

In [12]: (p == 1).sum(axis=0)
Out[12]:
   0  1
0  3  1

In [13]: (p == 1).sum(axis=1)  # this is the default: .sum()
Out[13]:
   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  1  0  0

In [14]: (p == 1).sum(axis=2)
Out[14]:
   0  1  2
0  2  1  1
```

It might be you want to sum of this, the Series (I don't *think* you can do this part in one??):

```
In [15]: (p == 1).sum(axis=0).sum(axis=0)
Out[15]:
0    3
1    1
dtype: int64
```

To find the total number of items equal to 0, I'd use [`np.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) (though you could do `.sum().sum().sum()`):

```
In [21]: np.sum((p == 1).values)
Out[21]: 4
```

*Note: surprisingly the .values is required here.*

Comment: Thank you Andy Hayden. The np.sum((p==1).values) works perfect!